# be into (somebody) for something (owe somebody or be owed by somebody?)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The bank was into her for $100,000. (The bank is the party that receives the money from her.)

> I'm into him for a thousand dollars. (The 'I' is the party that gives the money to him.)

> By the time he’d fixed the leak, I was into him for $500. (The context gives the clue who should pay)

What's the exact literal meaning of "be into (somebody) for something"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are 'into someone' for a sum of money, that means you owe that person that sum of money. That person is a creditor (of you), and you are a debtor (of that person).

I am into the bank for $10,000 = I owe the bank $10,000. The bank is my creditor, and I am its debtor.

The bank is into me for $10,000 = the bank owes me $10,000. The bank is my debtor, and I am the bank's creditor.

Joe is into Bill for $50 = Joe owes Bill $50.

> Definition of be into (someone) for
>
> US, informal
>
> to owe someone (an amount of money)
>
> I'm into him for a thousand dollars.

[Be into someone (idiom) (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20into%20%28someone%29%20for)

Comment: In "A is into B for an amount of money", A is always the debtor?

Comment: @BEBYGONES - that is what the dictionary says.

Comment: What about in real life English world? Because my dictonary says 'the bank is a creditor' for my first example sentence.

Comment: What dictionary says that?

Comment: https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/enko/50b2f0fe569f4161ab94442111465c6d

Comment: It says "US informal to owe someone (an amount of money)". I can't see 'the bank is a creditor' on that page.

Comment: The explanation in Korean says the bank is a creditor. You should unfold the button to see the example sentence.

Comment: Have you read what 'creditor' means in a dictionary?

Comment: In 'accounting', a 'creditor' means the party who lends money.

Comment: Come to think of it now, my dictonary maybe made a mistake in translating it into Korean.

Comment: Ah, now we get to the truth.

Comment: At least the explanation in Korean says 'the bank' should receive the money from her. You can put the Korean sentence into an automatic translator.